# R Shiny set DataTable column width

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to set the width of columns in a DataTable rendered in Shiny and am not able to implement it using the aoColumnDefs options. Has anyone tried this before ? My table has 1 text followed by 3 numeric columns. The numeric columns need to be narrower and the 1st column (text) wider.

```
output$result <- renderDataTable({
z <- as(dataInput(), "data.frame")
setnames(z, c("Rules", "Support", "Confidence", "StatDep"))
z
}, options = list(aLengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), iDisplayLength = 5, bSortClasses = TRUE,
              aoColumnDefs = list(sWidth = "50px", aTargets = list(1))))
```

Thanks,

- Raj.

** Update ** This seems to be working, but there might be other options to do this as well.

```
output$result <- renderDataTable({
z <- as(dataInput(), "data.frame")
setnames(z, c("Rules", "Support", "Confidence", "StatDep"))
z
}, options = list(aLengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), iDisplayLength = 5, bSortClasses = TRUE,
              bAutoWidth = FALSE,
              aoColumn = list(list(sWidth = "150px", sWidth = "30px",
                                       sWidth = "30px", sWidth = "30px"))
                                  ))
```

Answer (score 61):

Try this

```
#OUTPUT - dtdata
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),b=c("A","B","C","D","E"))
},
options = list(
  autoWidth = TRUE,
  columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))
))
```

Sets the width of all columns to 200px.

To set width of selected columns, change `targets`to a number or vector.

```
targets = c(1,3)
```

Comment: To set different column widths for multiple columns you can use:          
 columnDefs = (list(list(width = '200px', targets =c(0, 2)),
                               list(width = '80px', targets =c(6))))

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The actual solution is to set option `scrollX = TRUE` (https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/29#issuecomment-162093790) then specify column widths using CSS (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44110579/8605348).

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: It **DOES** work, [source](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html)

Answer (score 15):

By the way, in case you're like me and never used DataTables before version 1.10 came out -- The examples above confused me at first, because they use the notation that was used in version 1.9 but 1.10 introduces new notation:
http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert

I've been using the new syntax, i.e.,

columnDefs instead of aoColumnDefs
http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs

width instead of sWidth
http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width
etc.

Comment: for those of us who are not familiar with javascript, translating the datatable documentation at their website e.g. [http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width] to an equivalent `R` code becomes difficult. Esp the level of nesting needed in a list is not clear by looking at the JSON syntax. Is there any tips around that?

Comment: Useful to know about the new notation, but this answer does not give or point to an up-to-date DT syntax to use.

Comment: @geotheory [here you go](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html)