# R shiny datatable filter box size to narrow to see text

Tags: r, filter, datatable, shiny, dt

I'm building an R shiny dashboard and when I put my data in a table using the DT package and renderdatatable(). At the top of each column, I have filters, the search box is too narrow to see the text and select an option. Here's an image:

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to increase the width?

Here's my code for the datatable code in the server.r:

```
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({    
    data <- rv$data
    if (input$sour != "All") {
      data <- data[data[,1] == input$sour,]
    }else{data}
    if (input$sour1 != "All") {
      data <-data[data[,2] == input$sour1,]
    }else{data}
    if (input$tran != "All") {
      data <-data[data[,3] == input$tran,]
    }else{data}
  },filter='top'))
```

here's the code in the ui.r:

```
 tabItem(tabName = "ResultsTable",
              fluidPage(  
                headerPanel(
                  h1("List", align="center",  style = "font-family: 'Verdana';font-weight: 800; line-height: 1.1;   color: #151515;")),
                # fluidRow(
                #     column(8, DT::dataTableOutput("table",width = "100%"),offset = 2)))),
                #                 # Create a new Row in the UI for selectInputs
                fluidRow(

                  column(4,
                         selectInput("sour",
                                     "Name:",
                                     c("All",
                                       unique(as.character(df[,1]))))
                  ),
                  column(4,
                         selectInput("sour1",
                                     "Number:",
                                     c("All",
                                       unique(as.character(df[,2]))))
                  ),
                  column(4,
                         selectInput("tran",
                                     "Code:",
                                     c("All",
                                       unique(as.character(df[,3])))))),
                # Create a new row for the table.
                fluidRow(column(11, DT::dataTableOutput("table",width = "95%")))))
```

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
 output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({    
    data <- rv$data
    if (input$sour != "All") {
      data <- data[data[,1] == input$sour,]
    }else{data}
    if (input$sour1 != "All") {
      data <-data[data[,2] == input$sour1,]
    }else{data}
    if (input$tran != "All") {
      data <-data[data[,3] == input$tran,]
    }else{data}
  },filter='top',options = list(
    autoWidth = TRUE,
    columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))
  )))
```

Comment: A hackish way is to rename "Date List" column to be a long string without spaces, e.g. to "DateList" or "Date_List". The shiny app will make the drop down at least as wide as that string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem using CSS:

```
input {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

You can also apply this style to `factor` filters only:

```
td[data-type="factor"] input {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Put `my.css` file in `www` subdirectory, and link to it:

```
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        tags$head(
            tags$link(
                rel = "stylesheet",
                type = "text/css",
                href = "my.css")
        ),

        DT::dataTableOutput(...)
    )
```

Comment: This does make it so that the selection boxes are big enough, but it appears that this can lead to issues with the filters maligning with the column names.

Answer (score 4):

[A similar question was answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205410/r-shiny-set-datatable-column-width?rq=1)

Also, in order [to use range sliders to filter rows within ranges](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/), consider converting the "Date List" column to the date format using `as.Date()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did try that, but it had no impact. It's not necessarily the column width I'm trying to extend, but the width of the drop down filter box.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with some javascript, specifically by targeting the `selectize-dropdown-content` via a headerCallback:

```
headerCallback <- c("function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
                      "  var td = $('td');",
                      "  var factor_td = td.filter(function (d) {
                          return($(this)[0].attributes[0].value == 'factor');
                         })",
                      "  factor_td.each(function(d){
                          var factor_dropdown = factor_td[d].childNodes[3].childNodes[2].childNodes[1];
                          var new_dropdown = factor_dropdown.childNodes[0];
                          factor_dropdown.setAttribute('style','background-color:transparent; border:transparent; box-shadow:none')
                          new_dropdown.setAttribute('style','width:fit-content; background-color:white; border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); border-radius:4px; box-shadow:0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175); max-height:100px');
                         });")
```

This works by filtering for all inputs with a data-type of factor - then for each input it selects the selectize-dropdown-content and adds some CSS.

To use this with datatable just add it to the options list:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)
server <- function(input,output,session){
      headerCallback <- c("function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
                      "  var td = $('td');",
                      "  var factor_td = td.filter(function (d) {
                          return($(this)[0].attributes[0].value == 'factor');
                         })",
                      "  factor_td.each(function(d){
                          var factor_dropdown = factor_td[d].childNodes[3].childNodes[2].childNodes[1];
                          var new_dropdown = factor_dropdown.childNodes[0];
                          factor_dropdown.setAttribute('style','background-color:transparent; border:transparent; box-shadow:none')
                          new_dropdown.setAttribute('style','width:fit-content; background-color:white; border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); border-radius:4px; box-shadow:0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175); max-height:100px');
                         });")
  data_use <- as.data.frame(datasets::USPersonalExpenditure)
  data_use$category <- as.factor(row.names(data_use))
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(data = data_use,
              filter = "top",
              options = list(
                headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
              )
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Note: I was unable to just select `selectize-dropdown-content` directly since I have other dropdowns that I didn't want to change, hence why I select it indirectly using a lot of `childNodes` arguments.

Answer (score -2):

Yihui's solution here seems to work very well:
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/172

`datatable(..., options = list(autoWidth = TRUE))`