# How to format tagList to make a columnwise layout in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am making an app where I have **a variable number of input fields**. These field are alternating `selectizeInput()` and `textInput()` fields, where the ID increments by 1 with each set of both inputs.
I achieved generating this with some inspiration from [R Shiny: How to dynamically append arbitrary number of input widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083286/r-shiny-how-to-dynamically-append-arbitrary-number-of-input-widgets)

Now, I would like to alter the layout of the input widgets in my taglist.
With the current code, all tags in `inputTagList` that appended using `tagAppendChild()`, are printed below the previous in my app.

**I would like them to be printed in two columns**, where the first tag is at the top left, the second at the top right, the third on the second row left, then second row right, etc.
This means that all `selectizeInput()` fields, named `namesInput`, are on the left on the right are the `textInput()` fields named `groupInput`.

**I took the essential items from my app to make a runnable example:**

```
library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(sliderInput('numGroups','Number of      Groups',min=1,max=20,value=2,step=1),
              uiOutput("allInputs"))
)

 server <- function(input, output) {

    output$allInputs <- renderUI({
    inputTagList <- NULL
    inputTagList <- tagList()

    ## Define options for each input field
    opts <- as.list(paste0('Level',1:5))
    names(opts) <- sapply(opts,function(x) x)

    ## Get number of groups from sliderinput
    k <- input$numGroups

    for(i in 1:k) {
      # Define unique input id and label
      newInputId <- paste0("group", i)
      newInputLabel <- paste("Group levels", i)
      newInputId2 <- paste0("name", i)
      newInputLabel2 <- paste("Group name", i)
      newInputValue2 <- paste("Group",i)
      # Define new input

      namesInput <- selectizeInput(newInputId, newInputLabel,
                                   choices=opts,
                                   multiple=T)
          groupInput <- textInput(newInputId2, label = newInputLabel2, value = newInputValue2)

      # Append new input to list of existing inputs
      inputTagList <- tagAppendChild(inputTagList, namesInput)
      inputTagList <- tagAppendChild(inputTagList, groupInput)
    } # return list of inputs
    inputTagList
  })

}

# Run the application
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Unfortunately there were no responses, so I dug a bit deeper. The answer is actually ridiculously simple: Just add `column(6,...)` to both tags. Result:       `namesInput <- column(6,selectizeInput(newInputId, newInputLabel,`
                                   `choices=opts,`
                                   `multiple=T))`
      `groupInput <- column(6,textInput(newInputId2, label = newInputLabel2, value = newInputValue2))`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to reply nor upvote, but your comment to your question is exactly what I was looking for and worked perfectly! You should post this as an answer,